# SVN users set-up

Tags: svn

I've recently set up a SVN to work on my collaborative university homework with my colleague.

It's actually working that way:

root
/class1
   /tp1
      /trunk
   /tp2
      /trunk
/class2
   /tp1
      /trunk

Currently, there is only the "test" user that have access to the svn over ssh.
I would like to know if I can set-up different user with different permission for different class and different project.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.04.

Comment: This is not really a programming question

Comment: Voting to migrate to serverfault.

Comment: That's rather a server configuration question, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set user and group access independently for each project, or even each directory if you like. The whole explanation can be found in the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth) online book (link to the section you are interested in).